# Get element if the most on top and visible in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the id of the div witch is on top on my page.

Actually, I have this HTML:

```
<div class="items"> <!-- Scrollable -->
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="item1">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
        <div id="item2">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
        <div id="item3">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
        <div id="item4">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
     </div>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
jQuery('.items').scroll(function() {
    var distance = $('.items div').offset().top;
    console.log(distance);
});
```

How can I get when the div `items` is scrolled I can get the id of the div witch is the `most visible on top` ?

Thanks.

Comment: The title and description could use a little help. : )

Comment: You should check out the jquery.inview plugin. It may have some use for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         jQuery('.items').scroll(function() {
            var top = $(this).children().first();
            $(this).children().each(function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset().top;
                if(offset < 0 && offset >= -$(this).height()){
                    top = $(this);
                    return false; //"break"
                }
            });

            console.log(top.attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

See working example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/theuncsc/

Comment: Wow! Perfectly what I expected. Thanks @Kamil!

Comment: Again me: what about if my structure change a little bit like in my edited question please ?